# Changing document source root on nginx + hhvm?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

I'm tring to configure hhvm and nginx to work on php files at /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.com directory

- first i installed hhvm and nginx from apt get and it's works fine from default directory
- then i change fastcgi config of /etc/nginx/hhvm.conf from

  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

to

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.com$fastcgi_script_name;
```

then i add source root to  vim /etc/hhvm/server.ini

```
hhvm.server.source_root = /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.come
```

then restarted both nginx and hhvm but still I'm getting php file from default web root not from /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.come

here is config file for virtual host

```
    server {
listen 80;

server_name  www.mysite.se;

        access_log /var/log/www.mysite.se.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/www.mysite.se.error_log;

location / {
root   /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.se;
index  index.php index.htm;

if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
        rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
}

#include hhvm.conf;

        location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.se$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```

when i did a request html files get load from /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.se without a problem but php files get load from default nginx folder

Comment: Not enough info. Please post the full server config for this virtual host.

Comment: What on earth is all that `rule_1` mess?

Comment: if i removed that still not working. same config work fine with php-fpm not hhvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in on nginx site configuration file

the root need to be in server block not the location block.

Fore those you are willing to configure nginx with hhvm here is how to do it.

I remanded for you to use ubuntu.

- sudo su <- to get root accsess
- apt-get install nginx
- wget http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hhvm/hhvm_3.2.0~trusty_amd64.deb <- download based on os version
- dpkg -i hhvm_3.2.0~trusty_amd64.deb <- current production with is 3.3.0 has a issue in xml bug https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3797
- if you need to send out email smtp mail not yet work on hhvm
- apt-get install sendmail
- now configure nginx virtual host config then it's need to work

server {
    listen 80;

```
server_name  www.mysite.se;
root   /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.se;

        access_log /var/log/www.mysite.se.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/www.mysite.se.error_log;

location / {
index  index.php index.htm;

if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
        rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
}

#include hhvm.conf;

        location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/ubuntu/www/www.mysite.se$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```